# Not able to fetch namespace, nodes & pods data from Alibaba cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes, alibaba-cloud

I have created a cluster on Alibaba.

I need to fetch cluster data in the Golang project.

Getting below error from API:

```
{
  "Code": 403,
  "Message": "namespaces is forbidden: User \"281247226166595041\" cannot list resource \"namespaces\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"
}
```

Tried accessing it via kubectl:

```
$ kubectl get namespace
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "225396037912844073" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

Not able to fetch data for cluster created by another user.

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's issue of authentication

Your user doesn't have access to list that namespace.

You need to update the RBAC or user access, or however, you are authenticating the Go client into Kubernetes.

If you are using the service account to give access check the RBAC.

Give service account **cluster-admin** access

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: <new-account-name>
  namespace: <namespace>

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: go-rbac
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

> kubectl apply -f .yaml

If you are running outside the cluster make sure your script pointing to correct **kubeconfig**

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"

  "k8s.io/client-go/1.5/kubernetes"
  "k8s.io/client-go/1.5/pkg/api/v1"
  "k8s.io/client-go/1.5/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main()  {
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", <kube-config-path>)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }

    c, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
```

Running **inside** the custer

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    //
    // Uncomment to load all auth plugins
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth"
    //
    // Or uncomment to load specific auth plugins
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/azure"
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/gcp"
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/oidc"
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/openstack"
)

func main() {
    // creates the in-cluster config
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // creates the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
```

Example : https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/main.go

Comment: How can I get the service account for the Alibaba cluster, Could you please help me with this?

Comment: how you are running code ? inside the container on K8s or outside of K8s cluster ?

Comment: @PranitaT  are you still facing issues ? could you please update the status if it's worked for you.